# TempData and Linq

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

The main Linq query is in the Controller (resulted as Model in Razor).
I have TempData in Razor form and if it is null I assign Linq expression from Model to it (Model -> Linq filtering -> ToList() -> assign List to TempData -> TempData.Keep).

I noticed that if to change data outside the form (TempData is not changed because it's not null) the expression keeped by TempData honor these ouside changes.

Am I correct if I think about above as every reading of my TempData does querying this List (various set of data) again every time?
I mean that TempData does not keep data set but the query which is raised when to read it. But for egzample if I break debugger on it, I see a set of data which I can browse.

Comment: It is impossible to answer this question without seeing the code you mention. Please include it.

Comment: Currently I have changed a code doing different approach. Thanks.